# Angular CLI // TypeScript // Chrome Debugging > Arrow function loses context

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, this, angular-cli, arrow-functions

I'm struggling since a few days with a problem I can't explain:

- I have an Angular 4 CLI project running fine
- I have an arrow function in one of my component's method that sets a property in my component
- When I put a breakpoint in Chrome dev tools (or VS Code debugger against Chrome, same behavior) in my arrow function, the **this context is not bound to the component**
- BUT if I execute the code, it works well

Example code:

```
export class MyComponent {

  private message = 'Im here!';

  constructor() {
    const test = () => {
      console.log(this.message);
    };

    test();
  }

}
```

If I put a breakpoint on a line with console.log(this.message), this context will be **undefined** in the debugger watch, but at execution, it will write 'Im here!' in my console.

Have you ever experienced this problem before? Is there a problem with my source maps, idk?

Comment: So **_this**, the context variable generated by the transpiler is recognized by the debugger. This works but is not handy, isn't there a way to use the "real"  **this** context

Comment: I'm having the same problem, just that in chrome dev tools I can see "this" value, but in vscode it is undefined

Comment: Try "_this" instead of "this". I figured out that it's because of the way the transpiler generates the output js code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because arrow function does not bind its own this, it sets the this variable from its outer environment

refer to this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

and since the actual Google Chrome supports arrow functions you can see the  message defined when you execute the arrow function ...

On the other hand since angular use a transpiler to work with ECMA6, it actually translates your code to ECMA5, which in that case the this arrow function will be translated to a ecma5 function that doesn't has a reference to the this variable and that is why you see is undefined...

A workaround would be using

```
constructor() {
   let self = this;
    const test = () => {
      console.log(self.message);
    };

    test();
  }
```

Comment: Transpiled from TS to ES5, but it is the same principle.
Unfortunately this can't work for the simple reason that the current context is lost, so even the **self** variable wont be visible.

Answer (score 0):

When you run code in constructor with arrow function it loses the context.

What you can do to check things when the component is being initialized is to implements OnInit and define ngOnInit() function :

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  private message = 'Im here!';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const test = () => {
      console.log(this.message);
    };

    test();
    }

}
```

Comment: I already tried it before, result is the same, see http://nsa39.casimages.com/img/2017/10/17/171017032635702838.png

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example code and it worked well for me in both the *constructor* and *ngOnInit* variants. I was able to see the real value of the `this` in my debugger. So the code is correct. Your debugger apparently doesn't resolve the reference from the map file correctly.

I noticed that when I was looking at another variable in the Debugger the popup with the word `undefined` looked differently than the one on your screenshot. Yours is a simple rectangle, whereas mine is an rectangle with a triangle at the bottom pointing to the variable. Although Chrome is supposed to update itself automatically, just in case, make sure you are using the latest version.